# Unable to register Autofac Multitenant Container

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions, autofac

I have been trying to incorporate an Autofac multitenant container in my Azure Function v4 isolated app targeting .Net Framework 4.8. However, I am aware that this is not supported because the Azure Function cannot identify the tenant. Nevertheless, the main web project in my solution already uses a multitenant container and creates child scopes from it. The DLL that the Azure Function will be calling also resolves the child scope from the multitenant container. Therefore, I need to find a way to register the multitenant container in the Azure Function.

I've installed Autofac.Multitenant nuget package and creates an Autofac bootstrapper as following:

```
   internal static class AutofacBootstrapper
    {
        
        internal static void Setup(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
       
            //Register Modules
            ...


            var container = builder.Build();

            var multiTenantContainer =
                new MultitenantContainer(new TenantIdentityStrategy(), container);

            CompositionRoot.SetContainer(multiTenantContainer);
        }
    }
```

And in the Program.cs I have this:

```
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FunctionsDebugger.Enable();

            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(AutofacBootstrapper.Setup)
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

Now, the issue arises because I have already called container.Build() in the bootstrapper. When I attempt to call hostBuilder.Build(), it fails with an error message:

> Build() or Update() can only be called once on ContainerBuilder

How can I fix this issue? I have tried multiple approaches, but none of them have been successful so far.